# how to store 2*2 multi images to create a single image of size 250*250?

Tags: image, matlab

How could i split 250x250 image into 2X2 matrix (i.e, total 125 2x2 matrices i should get), again rearrange them to form a original image?

For example

```
img1 = imresize(imread('img.png'),[250 250]);
R = img1(:,:,1);
G = img1(:,:,2);
B = img1(:,:,3);
Y= cat(3,R,G,B);
```

Comment: Too long code. Please reduce it to provide a [_minimal_ working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You do realize that `Y` is the same as `img1`, right?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?  You will actually have 125*125 2x2 images.

```
img1 = imresize(imread('peppers.png'),[250 250]);

newimage= permute(reshape(img1,2,2,[],3),[1 2 4 3]);  % A 2x2x3x15625 matrix

restoredimage = reshape(permute(newimage,[1 2 4 3]),250,250,3);
```

From your code, Y = img1, so I'm not sure what you were trying to accomplish there.

Comment: For example, 'inimg=[250,250,3]; img1=[2,2,3]; img2=[2,2,3];...' if img1[1 2;3 4], img2[5 6;7 8].... all the img's are 3D images derived from the input image **inimg**. If i my required matrix is 'Y=[img1,....img125;...;img1125....img2125]' **Y=[250,250,3]** total i should get 125 matrices